# How to set the logged in user ID on a session (CodeIgniter)?

Tags: codeigniter

I am having trouble, getting the logged in user ID from the database...

This is my controller code :

```
        function validation(){

    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $query = $this->users_model->validate();

    if ($query){
        $this->users_model->get_userID($this->input->post('email'));
        $data = array( 
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'is_logged_in' => true,
        'user_id' => $user_id
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);            
        redirect('home');
    }
    else {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

This is my model function where I return the user id from the database:

```
       function get_userID($email){
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');       
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $user_id = $row->id;
        }
        return $user_id;

}
```

Everything works perfect, except that $user_id returns empty... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$user_id= $this->users_model->get_userID($this->input->post('email'));
```

Comment: @Rick Rhodes You should accept the question.Please find the gray tick mark under his answer and click on it. It should be green. If you do not mark the answer as correct soon you will not able to ask question here.

Answer (score 0):

try modifying the model function to this -

```php
function get_userID($email){
  $this->db->where('email',$email);
  $query = $this->db->get('users')->row_array(); // retrieves only first-row.
  return $query['id'];
}
```

In controller the function needs just a bit of modification as follows -

```php
function validation(){

    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $query = $this->users_model->validate();

    if($query){
        //$user_id was not assigned before :)
        $user_id = $this->users_model->get_userID($this->input->post('email')); 
        $data = array( 
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'is_logged_in' => true,
        'user_id' => $user_id
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);            
        redirect('home');
    }
    else {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

hope it helps,

faisal ahmed
[blog](http://www.thephpx.com/) / [site](http://www.faisalbd.com/)

Comment: btw looking again at your code the you should also check the validate() function because if it isn't returning TRUE the model function is never going to be accessed.