# Add user id to session data (codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter I'm trying to add the user id from the database to the session data.

I've looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624742/how-to-set-the-logged-in-user-id-on-a-session-codeigniter) and it didn't work for me

Controller code:

```
function validate_credentials()
{       
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $query = $this->users_model->validate();

    // if the users credentials validated...

    if($query) 
    {
        $user_id = $this->users_model->get_userID($this->input->post('email'));

        /* 

        I dont need to worry about insecure code because all incoming data 
        is filtered (set in config.php)

        */

        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'), 
            'is_logged_in' => true,
            'user_id' => $user_id
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('site/members');
    }

    else 

    {
        // incorrect username or password
        $this->index(); 
    }
}
```

Model code: (the column is called 'userID' in the users table of the db)

```
function get_userID($email){

    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    $query = $this->db->get('users');       

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $user_id = $row->userID;
    }

    return $user_id;

}
```

When I call the array in a view the user id does not appear.

```
<?php $this->session->userdata('user_id');?>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? Are you not seeing the $data array in the session on the next page?

Comment: Apologies; I've updated the original post. When I call the array from within a view I get nothing. <?php $this->session->userdata('user_id');?>

Comment: do the other variables appear?

Comment: You need to echo the sessions: `<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to view userID try..

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $this variable is not the same in a view as it is in a controller. If you want to refer to a session that way you have to get the $CI instance like this:

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI->session->userdata('user_id');
```

Comment: I believe that's incorrect, you can access the instance from the view because its an include file, its essentially part of the method from the controller. Your statement is true for a library or helper since those are separate from the CI super class.

Comment: I agree in principle, but in practice I've always had to do this in CI.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't work. It throws back 6 regardless of who I log in as.

Comment: What happens if you pull the session data in the site controller and put the value into the $data variable for the view? So before loading your members view you do $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');. Does that work?

Comment: What happens if you put session_write_close() just before your redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo your Query it always help to understand your problem  like try echo 
`$user_id` and `$data`
sometimes due to small errors you dont get values in your queries echo will show you the result